# Why cannot access my Django user immediately after creation?

Tags: django, django-forms

I create a new user using the following code:

```
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.clean_username()
        password = form.clean_password2()           
        new_user = form.save()
```

The above works fine.  Next I wish to login the user and redirect to the main page as follows

```
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/home")
```

I get the following error message:

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

A little debugging reveals 'user' is None.  However if I try to sign in the just created user it works i.e.  The user is created but

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Is not returning the user in my register function (the exact same code works subsequently in my login function).  The trace back has the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

It provides a small clue.  Is some sort of callback happening whereby

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

during registration is actually called before the user is created?  How can I authenticate and redirect my user immediately after registration?

Comment: Have you double checked the post parameters? I had a similar problem because I was expecting `request.POST['password']` instead of `request.POST['password1']`. Are you using the `if user is not None:` and `if user.is_active:` conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Django docs have a section for this and it looks like you're doing the same thing:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

My guess is that either the username/password is somehow wrong or the user is inactive (`user.is_active = False`)

Also, try setting the backend attr manually before calling `auth.login`

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
```